# Log into a website using Selenium, but continue working (while logged in) with requests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using Selenium and the Chrome web driver to log into my account on a website, but after the login, I want to use other libraries (such as `requests`) to interact with the website.

I am using Selenium to attempt to bypass reCAPTCHA v3, but I want to use the `requests` and `beautifulsoup` libraries to scrape data in the URL that comes after the login page (The URL that the login page redirects to, after logging in ).

Here is the code I've written for logging in, and a little snippet at the bottom which I plan to use for scraping the website post-login.

```py
import requests
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
action = ActionChains(driver)

url_1 = "https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-am/niv/users/sign_in"
url_2 = "https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-am/niv/account/settings/update_email"
email = "email"
password = 'password'
Headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36"
}


def login():

    driver.get(url_1)
    
    driver.find_element_by_id("user_email").send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id("user_password").send_keys(password)
    
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("icheckbox")[0].click()
    driver.find_elements_by_name("commit")[0].click()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(driver.current_url)

login()
test = requests.get(url, headers=Headers)
```

Comment: Which libraries do you want to use? What do you mean with "using other libraries"? What do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: I want to scrape data with it and by other libraries I mean requests, scrapy and beautifulsoup

Comment: You can `import` other libs at the beginning of you script and then you can use methods of these libs in your `def` (methods). E.g. if you want to use the `driver.current_url` in your `method requests.get(url, ...) ` you have to use `return` instead of "print" and then you have to change `login()` to s.th. like `url = login()`. But I am not sure, if selenium should be use in this manner.

Comment: thanks, I will try this and see if it works

Comment: And you should remove your credentials (username + password) from this posts

Comment: redirected me to the login page again! that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What logging in is actually doing is modifying your cookies to add a key, which verifies that you are logged in. What we can do with this info is to take the cookie data and reuse it for the Python `requests` module. Let's start by extracting the cookies from the webdriver like so:

```py
driver_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

Now that you have your cookies, you can inject them into future requests in the `cookies` parameter, like so:

```py
test = requests.get(url, headers=Headers, cookies=driver_cookies)
```

Comment: Wow, you are right the idea is right, but it says that list indices must be integers or slices and not dict. I guess I can figure that out by myself! Thanks again!

Comment: @artinghasivand how you solved 'list indices must be integers or slices and not dict' ?